# Javascript URI/Origin Override

Tags: javascript, iframe, host

I have a very specific challenge where a self contained website and assets are stored in a location that is not a web server and cannot be a web server.

I need to be able to provide staff a stand alone index.html file that they can run from their local computer which will reference the online location as a sort of external storage repository.

The website has a lot of assets and javascript... in many cases the javascript calls to assets using local paths such as images/image_file.png

Without manually updating all the asset paths within the website code, modifying hosts file... using iframe... is there a way with javascript alone to add prefix to all paths that come after in the document?

Almost like defining or setting origin which I don't believe is possible.

I had thought to read the code in with a parser and try and regex replace but was hoping for a simpler solution.

Thanks in advance for your consideration.

Comment: This is usually solved by running web server on localhost.  You need to be a lot more specific about how the assets are accessed.  If they are coming from a network share this is very very similar to the standard practice of proxying content that large numbers of web developers solve by running a local dev server to test their Apps.

Comment: I believe adding **<base href="https://example.com">** to the head of the HTML should work. Where example.com is the URL for the location of the files. This would then tell the browser that any relative URL should use that as the base. But you might run into security problems trying to run some javascript from the file without a web server.

Comment: I'll look into the base href tag option.

The asset and other files are actually stored in a sharepoint.  The scripting is disabled in our org sharepoint so iframe won't work and neither will embedded code.